error in bash while updating
This version of C:\Program Files (x86)\sf\client\bin\node.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.

Seems pretty straightforward. Not much you'll be able to do if you're still running Windows 8 (or earlier). I was able to sf update on Windows 10 22H2 (build number 19045) just a few minutes ago to 2.69.14 (which uses node v22.11.0). As usual, including more details (like OS version, what version of the cli you currently have, etc...) is helpful. Also keep in mind that we're not an official part of Salesforce, just a rag-tag group of (mostly) Salesforce customers volunteering our time and knowledge.
